# How can I use a QFutureWatcher with QtConcurrent::run() without a race condition

Tags: c++, qt, concurrency, future

If I understand the following code from the QFutureWatcher documentation correctly, then there is a race condition between the last to lines:

```
// Instantiate the objects and connect to the finished signal.
MyClass myObject;
QFutureWatcher<int> watcher;
connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(finished()), &myObject, SLOT(handleFinished()));

// Start the computation.
QFuture<int> future = QtConcurrent::run(...);
watcher.setFuture(future);
```

If the function `...` in the `QtConcurrent::run(...)` finishes before the next line is called, then the `watcher.finished()` signal will never be triggered. Is my assumption correct? How do I work around this bug?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfuturewatcher.html#setFuture

> One of the signals might be emitted for the current state of the
>   future. For example, if the future is already stopped, the finished
>   signal will be emitted.

In other words, if `QtConcurrent::run(...)` completes before `setFuture` is called, `setFuture` will still emit a signal on the current state of the `QFuture`. So, you don't need to do anything in order to avoid a race condition.

However, depending on the rest of your code, you may need to call `QFuture::waitForFinished()` in order to ensure that your `MyClass`, `QFuture` and `QFutureWatcher` do not go out of scope *before* `QtConcurrent::run(...)` completes.

Answer (score 0):

I was running this snipped in a unit test and `QSignalSpy` was not getting the signals from `QFutureWatcher`. I solved the issue by calling explicitely `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` before the check:

```cpp
QFutureWatcher<int> watcher;
QSignalSpy spy(&watcher, &QFutureWatcher<int>::finished);

QFuture<int> future = QtConcurrent::run([](){
    qDebug() << "compute";
    return 42;
});
watcher.setFuture(future);
QCOMPARE(watcher.result(), 42);
QCOMPARE(spy.count(), 0);
QCoreApplication::processEvents();
QCOMPARE(spy.count(), 1);
```

The signal is probably emitted from a thread, and in this situation, the signal is queued instead of being directly executed.